# White gap on mobile devices

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I'm designing a Wordpress website for one of my clients and I'm getting a strange white gap on mobile devices.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

The website is:

http://bmurphyhomes.com

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the sidebar that is taking the space

Answer (score -1):

jup. the sidebar. you should go for a fluid or responsive template if you want to optimize it for mobile. Take a look at twitter bootstrap (responsive) or zurb foundation (fluid). Both of them are free and there are tons of tutorials and starter themes for wordpress which you could edit to fit your design.

Herre you can find a foundation boilerplate: http://foundationpress.olefredrik.com/ (download here: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/1214-foundation-5--wordpress )
or here you can find a bootstrap boilerplate (btw: I prefere bootstrap but this is like a favorite color everyone has his own fav.)

just resize your browser to see what happens to the sidebar and elements.

As allways: appreciate the creator (it wasn't me) and buy them a beer if there's a link and take a look at the licence!